# Using meshlabxml remiss.simplify for mesh simplification

Tags: python, mesh, point, point-clouds, meshlab

I have a `.obj` file with vertices and faces. I want to reduce the number of faces by mesh simplification and I intend to use [meshlabxml](https://github.com/3DLIRIOUS/MeshLabXML) to do that. The remesh.simplify function seems approprate for the task.

Can somebody explain the parameters and how I can use my `.obj` file to use for this mesh simplification function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [quadric-mesh-simplification](https://github.com/jannessm/quadric-mesh-simplification) repo.